# Tarruda datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

i'm trying to use tarruda datetimepicker, all is ok until,  i click on time table, i later cannot switch back to calendar view, i paralelly use core admin theme, i dont know if that is which brokes down it, but  to switch from calendar to time this line works,

`<li class="picker-switch accordion-toggle"><a><i class="icon-time"></i></a></li>`

but when i'm in time mode

`<li class="picker-switch accordion-toggle"><a><i class="icon-calendar"></i></a></li>`

this line doesnt work anymore, and icon doesn't shows, despite i know that i have this icon, coz i tried lot of other datetimepicker, but no error shows in console too. maybe there's some collisions in core admin theme?

Comment: [Project site](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker) says it's no longer maintained and points to [Eonasadn's fork](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

Comment: I cant get it working, cause i'm using core admin theme, and there's is no glyphicons and mape that JS file is made for using with glyphicons..

Comment: @Michael Have you tried my fork? Did you get your issue resolved? Please let me know if I can help

Comment: @Eonasdan i somehow solved it with tarruda's version, i added bootstrap.js(from getboostrap.com) and collapse plugin was giving it work.

Dont know what was the real cause of the problem, but probably next time i will use your version, thanks! :)
I'm using Core Admin theme, and dont know why this was a reason, cause there are collapse too, but solved my problem.